# Having multiple properties incrementing one variable. Simple check of its value?

Tags: c#, variables, properties

I have 10 properties where when each is set it increments the value of variable `Value`. When the value of `Value` is 10, the app will end. But it seems to be awkward to write the same condition into each of them like this:

```
int Value=0;
int A
{
   set
   {
     a=value;
     Value++;
     if(Value>10) ... //check here
   }
}
int B
{
   set
   {
     b=value;
     Value++;
     if(Value>10)  //check here again
   }
}
```

How can I simplify checking its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int counter;
private int b;
private int a;

public int A
{
    set 
    {
         counter++;
         a = value;
         CheckCounter();
    }
}

public int B    {
    set 
    {
         counter++;
         b = value;
         CheckCounter();
    }
}


public void CheckCounter()
{
     if (counter>10)
     {
         //Do something
     }
}
```

or make counter a property..

```
private int Counter
{
    set
    {
        counter = value;
        CheckCounter();
    }
    get
    {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

and use this when incrementing..

```
Counter++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a private property for Value and in the setter of that property, if the value is set to above 10, exit the application.

```
private int value=0;
private int a, b;

public int A
{
   set
   {
      this.a = value;
      Value++;
   }
   get { return this.a; }
}
public int B
{
   set
   {
      this.b = value;
      Value++;
   }
   get { return this.b; }
}
private int Value
{
   set
   {
      this.value = value;
      if (this.value > 10)
      {
         // Exit.
      }
   }
   get { return this.value; }
}
```

Comment: I know, I was merely trying to keep the example short. I've updated my answer to include getter now though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your properties are in a class which has other responsibilities than exiting the program when the counter hits 10. If so, I would remove the logic of checking the counter and exiting the app from the class.
Maybe you can use an event. The subscriber to this event will be notified when Value hits 10 (you could actually make "10" configurable, but this is just a short example) and exit the app.

```
class YourClass {
    public event ValueHandler ValueIs10;
    public EventArgs e = null;
    public delegate void ValueHandler(YourClass m, EventArgs e);

    private int _value=0;

    public int Value {
        get {return _value;}
        private set {
            _value=value;
            if(_value==10 && ValueIs10 != null) ValueIs10(this, e);
        }
    }

    public int A
    {
       set
       {
         a=value;
         Value++;
       }
    }

    public int B
    {
       set
       {
         b=value;
         Value++;
       }
    }  

    // ...
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the best answer. While other answers work this one has the best design.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers from @Richard and @Emil are correct, but to make your code more expandable in the future, it's better to implement the built-in [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

```
class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _counter = 0;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, arg) =>
        {
            // if (_counter > 10) Exit();
            // from arg you can know what property is changed
            // which is probably used for future
        };

    private int _number;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set
        {
          //here is another unclear point in your question
          //will the counter increases when setting a.Number = 100 
          //but it's already 100 before setting
            if (_number != value)
            {
                _number = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Number"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```